# how to use regex to add leading zero

Tags: regex, notepad++

Question - what is the shortest form of regex to add a leading zero into a found pattern?

I want to add a leading zero to any number that matches this regex pattern

`[(][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][-][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][-][0-9][0-9][)]`

I am using Notepad++.

Comment: Please post a sample text and expected output. What have you tried?

Comment: You mean you want to add a leading zero in front of a number that matches `\(\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{2}\)`?

Comment: Can't you just `concatenate` a `0` on to it if it does match that pattern? Example: `newString = "0" + matchedPatter;`

Answer (score 0):

In Notepad++ Regex Replace, you use $n to represent the nth capture group for replacement:

```
Search for: [(]([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][-][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][-][0-9][0-9])[)]
Replace with: (0$1)
```